# Adding custom button in tableview with tag

Tags: ios, button, tags, tableview

Hello everyone, 
          I am trying to add custom button with tag related to indexPath.row. I can view the tag value correctly if I don't insert new row into tableview. But, when I insert new row, my tag value of new row is not correct if the inserted row is not within 0 to 9 (iphone 5 can show up to that). On iphone, I need to scroll down to see.
 

 However, with the same code, I can get my tag value correctly on my ipad. I don't need to scroll down table view on my ipad to see all my row.I would like to know why it happen and how to solve.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"dialoguesTableCell";
    dialoguesCell *cell = [tableViewdequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[dialoguesCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
            reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

    UIButton *yourButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [yourButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1StarBlank.png"]     forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [yourButton setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonSelected:)   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    yourButton.tag=indexPath.row;
    yourButton.frame = CGRectMake(5, 10, 40, 25);
    [cell addSubview:yourButton];
    return cell;


}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath
{
   NSIndexPath *indexPathstoinsert = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row+1     inSection:section];
   NSArray *indexPathsToInsertArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPathstoinsert];
   [[self mainTableView] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToInsertArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];

}
```

Comment: Please don’t use signatures or taglines in your posts, or they will be removed. See [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not working correctly because the UITableView **reuses** cells
 
when you scroll down, the first cells arent visible anymore and are reused.

if the table is .. 'small' you can just work around it by **not reusing cells**
**BUT** if the table isnt just a few entries but a lot of data you really want to change your way

assign the tag for the button in:
 `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

e.g.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIButton *b = nil;
    for(UIView *v in cell.subviews) {
        if([v isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            b = (UIButton*)v;
            break;
        }
    }

    b.tag = indePath.row;
}
```

---

in the commment you mentioned another problem: the buttons are hidden in your `didSelectRow` method and are then gone from other cells too after scrolling. SAME issue: the cell objects are **REUSED** by the tableview. dont store state in reusable cells!

Instead have a 'model' tree or array that remembers the state : text, image, tag, hide:yes/no

`NSArray *myTableContents`

```
 NSMutableDictionary *d1 = [@{@"text:@"bla", @"hidden":@NO} mutableCopy];
 NSMutableDictionary *d2 = [@{@"text:@"bloo", @"hidden":@NO} mutableCopy];
 NSMutableDictionary *d3 = [@{@"text:@"foo", @"hidden":@NO} mutableCopy];
 myTableContents = @[d1,d2,d3];
```

THEN always use THAT array in numberOfRows and in viewForRow and modify it in didSelectEntry

Comment: Thanks.It work.I wana do another step relating to this case. I am trying to hide that button in the new inserted row. But, when I scroll up or down, the other buttons are hidden.How should I do?----
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     NSIndexPath *favouriteIndexpath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:section];
            UITableViewCell *cellktl = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:favouriteIndexpath];
            UIButton *exerciseDate = [cellktl viewWithTag:indexPath.row];
            exerciseDate.hidden=YES;
}

Comment: same reason, cells are reused after didSelect .. you need some 'model' to remember what rows are hidden and then reapply that in willDisplay.. ill write some more code for you

Comment: Thanks. It will work. Can you please show a little more how to use that array? Shall I write in - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{..........}
And then, I dont know what is viewForRow.  I would like to know how to use it.